# Get write access only to defined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read access to a complete database but I cannot write.

This causes a problem since I want to compare the database data with external data. (e.g. spreadsheets)

The most efficient solution would be if I can create a new table in that database with the spreadsheet its data.

I it possible to create a table which I can write to and disable writing on the rest of the database?

Comment: read read-only data into memory. ditto with spreadsheets. Fun and Profit.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit or maybe give me a searchterm I can google for :) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mitch his answer I found this explanation. http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html This seems to work an solve my problem.